# Why does response.json() work on my PC but not on my Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, json, response, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to use the Raspberry Pi to get data from a json file. It works fine if i run the script on my pc, but at the Raspberry i get these Errors:

Code:

```
import requests

headers = {
            "Accept": "*/*",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            "Connection": "keep-alive",
            "DNT": "1",
            "Host": "api.sofascore.com",
            "Origin": "https://www.sofascore.com",
            "Pragma": "no-cache",
            "Referer": "https://www.sofascore.com/",
            "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
            "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
            "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-site",
            "Sec-GPC": "1",
            "TE": "trailers",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
           
}

url = "https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/sport/football/scheduled-events/2023-05-29"
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers).json()
```

Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 25, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 900, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 525, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

With other json files it works. I have tried a few things, the error means that the response is empty(?), but when I say 'print(response.text)' the (I think) encrypted text is printed. Is there another way to decrypt this or does anyone know why it doesn't work with that file on the Raspberry? Or do i miss something at the Header?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You should inspect (and maybe log) the status code before assuming the `get()` worked. `r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)` and then inspect or print `r.status_code`.

Comment: Didn't you import json on pc?

Comment: Thanks for your help, with BeautifulSoup it worked :)